# Why was this questions closed, "Crowdsourcing game play advice, is it flawed?"

Tags: support

The question, [crowdsourcing-game-play-advice-is-it-flawed](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/169/crowdsourcing-game-play-advice-is-it-flawed) was "closed as not a real question", any thoughts on why it is not a real question?

Meaning to me it seems if it was not a real question, a real answer would not be possible, and there is a real answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was not involved in the closing, but here's how I see it...

I think Daniel summed it up well in his comment:

> Basically, your question is very broad. It's like asking "what value does playing chess have?" Do you want to know why people like it? What the difference between "crowdsourced" games and OTB games tends to be? What do you want to know about it? You do ask "is it flawed?", but that seems like asking "are chess players flawed?"

To me, your question reads like a great discussion starter, but I'm not sure that it's an answerable question in our Q&A format.

Comment: +1 @Anna Lear: I'm not a chess player either, which might explain the gap in my understanding. Guess at this point if it's a bad question, I'd request it be delete; which I'm unable to do, since there's an answer. Again, thanks!

Comment: @blunders I can remove it for you, if you like.

Comment: Yes, thanks, sorry for the trouble!

Comment: @AnnaLear *[Nudge](http://chess.stackexchange.com/q/169/86)*